# MonoTouch.Dialog with UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller, monotouch.dialog

I'm creating universal app with MonoTouch. When running on iPad I use `UISplitViewController` and build multi level menu in master view (on the left side) with MonoTouch.Dialog.

Problem is, that when I touch first root element it opens new view which covers whole screen instead of being inside master split view.

Question is, how can I make so next root element opens inside same view as it's parent?

All the examples I could find usually has one level menu on the master view so when you touch it displays something on the detail view.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an `UISplitViewController` and your `CustomViewController`.

```
UISplitViewController split = ...;
CustomViewController controller = ...;
```

If you want to **push** the new controller on top of the current (master) one then use:

```
var root = new RootElement ();
var dvc = new DialogViewController (UITableViewStyle.Plain, root, true);
dvc.ActivateController (controller);
```

If you want to show the new controller in the details (right) section then use something like:

```
UISplitViewController split = ...;
var about = new StringElement ("About");
about.Tapped += delegate {
    split.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {
        split.ViewControllers [0],
        controller
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was quite embarrassing - I didn't use UINavigationController for master view! :(

Answer (score 0):

So you want your, I guess table, in the master to populate a new masterview on touch event?

I'm not familiar with .dialog but i've given an example as i know it:

take your `rootviewcontroller.parentviewcontroller.splitviewcontroller` and then populate the `viewcontrollers[0]`

```
var split =(uisplitviewcontroller)rootviewcontroller.parentviewcontroller.splitviewcontroller;
var nav = (uinavigationcontroller)split.viewcontrollers[0];
nav.pushviewcontroller(_yourView_);
```